# How to save the sudo password in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I need to use `tell Terminal ...` to do `... sudo ping ...` and I need it to repeat in many windows. It asks for the sudo password every time. Is there any way I can ask the user for the password and then make AppleScript enter it every time the sudo password is required?

A correctly-formed ping packet is typically 56 Bytes in size. I need to send larger ping packets (65507 Bytes) which is only allowed as root.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of temporarily storing your password in an application/AppleScript it might be easier to enable password-less `sudo` access to `ping`:

- Run `sudo visudo` to open the `sudoers` file
- Add a line `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ping` to give all users in the admin group password-less access to `sudo ping`

Afterwards you can just use `sudo ping` from Terminal or Applescript.

```
$ sudo ping -s 65000 askdifferent.com
PING askdifferent.com (104.27.182.101): 65000 data bytes
65008 bytes from 104.27.182.101: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=1250.724 ms
65008 bytes from 104.27.182.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=4.107 ms
65008 bytes from 104.27.182.101: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=3.943 ms
```

This works even without enabling the root account.

<sub>PS: **Never** edit `/etc/sudoers` directly, always use `sudo visudo` to do so. `visudo` applies basic sanity checks on the file when saving, you risk to lock yourself out of `sudo` if you get things wrong by editing the file directly.</sub>

Comment: This is certainly worth a +1. :)

Comment: The first paragraph. The actual solution is good.

Comment: @user151019 Ah, right, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: It’s worth +2 actually, but I only get one vote.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use the Keychain Access.app to create a new keychain item (in the example *jumboping*), the (your?) admin name (in the example *admin_name*) and the (your?) admin password:

[image: new keychain item]

2. Keychain item settings:

[image: Keychain item access control]

3. Use this Apple Script (replace the two occurences of admin_name with the name of the (your?) admin account):

   ```
   on getPassword(keychainItemName)
       local password
       set password to do shell script "security find-generic-password -a admin_name -s jumboping -w"
   end getPassword

   set my_password to getPassword("PassKeychainName")

   do shell script "ping -s 65000 -c 3 192.168.0.7" user name "admin_name" password my_password with administrator privileges
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   "PING 192.168.0.7 (192.168.0.7): 65000 data bytes
   65008 bytes from 192.168.0.7: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=4.865 ms
   65008 bytes from 192.168.0.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.874 ms
   65008 bytes from 192.168.0.7: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.878 ms

   --- 192.168.0.7 ping statistics ---
   3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
   round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.874/3.872/4.865/0.813 ms"
   ```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The `on getPassword(keychainItemName)` routine retrieves the admin (sudo) password from the keychain and stores it in a variable - you will be asked for the keychain password once to allow `security` to access the keychain item. The `do shell script "command" ... with administrator privileges` line executes *command* with admin privileges but without the need to enter the sudo password. The admin (sudo) password stored in the keychain item *jumboping* can be used in any AppleScript or shell script!</sub>

Comment: Is there any way that I can use AppleScript to add a keychain item?

Comment: Yes, **but** then the AppleScript contains the plain admin (sudo) password again!